# При нажатии RecycleView не правильно открывается FragmentTransparation почему?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

У меня есть RecycleView, при нажатии отображает Fragment, которы даже закрашивание фоне все действия делает вот так как на gif, что делать ?
[R.id.placeholder] = id main_activity.xml
    public class PeopleFragment extends Fragment {

```
public static final String DETAIL_FRIENDS_FRAGMENT = "fragment_detail_friend";
private List<Friend> users = new ArrayList<>();
protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private DateFriends db;
private List<Friend> list;
private FragmentActivity myContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db = new DateFriends(getActivity());

    list = db.getAllFriends();
    System.out.println("DONE");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    myContext = (FragmentActivity) context;
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.allPeople);
    FriendsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new FriendsRecyclerViewAdapter(implemets(users), new FriendsRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int index) {
            DetailFriendFragment detailFriendFragment = new DetailFriendFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(DetailFriendFragment.KEY_DETAIL, list.get(index).getName());
            detailFriendFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeholder, detailFriendFragment, DETAIL_FRIENDS_FRAGMENT);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SearchActivity.class));
        }
    });

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(),
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    return view;
}



public List<Friend> implemets(List<Friend> arr) {
    arr = list;
    return arr;
}


public void addUsers(Friend newFriend) {
    users.add(newFriend);
}

public List<Friend> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже на то, что фрагменту с деталями нужно указать бэкграунд